# Запрос к aprs.fi

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Как сделать запрос данных к `aprs.fi` через python?
Пробую так:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.aprs.fi/api/get?name=UB4FEU-11&what=loc&apikey=*****&format=json')
emit('aprs', {'response': response}, namespace='/mcc')
```

Вместо `***` используется `apikey`
Это не работает.
Может кто-то лучше поймёт и сможет объяснить: https://aprs.fi/page/api

Comment: Что значит «Это не работает»?

Comment: Этот пример не работает, хотя вроде как должен

Answer (score 0):

Кажется мне что APIKEY индивидуален и привязан к позывному -
 "To use the API you need to sign up for an user account on aprs.fi - **your API key** can be found in the account settings"
То есть в выражении  apikey=*****   вместо звездочек вы используете СВОЙ ключ ?

Comment: Думаете, автор вопроса до сих пор ищет ответ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from datetime import datetime # for convert APRS time

def aprs_request(callsign):
    aprs_apikey="2222222222222222"
    apiurl = "https://api.aprs.fi/api/get?name="+ str(callsign) + "&what=loc&apikey=" + str(aprs_apikey) + "&format=json"
    apireq = requests.get(apiurl)
    apidata = json.loads(apireq.text)
    for i in apidata['entries']:
        print("APRS Name: " + str(i['name']) +
              "| APRS Lat: " + str(i['lat']) +
              "| APRS Lng: " + str(i['lng']) +
              "| Lasttime seen: " + datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(i['lasttime'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') +
              "| Comment: " + str(i['comment']))
    time.sleep(5)
```

Output

```
APRS Name: UR0DUC| APRS Lat: 48.6175| APRS Lng: 22.34083| Lasttime seen: 2021-01-25 19:38:33| Comment: 438.650 -7.6 DMR
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]